# Transaction per hour in bigquery

Tags: date, google-bigquery, timestamp

Can someone help me, how to get transaction per hour in bigquery. Thank you in advance

I try this query but the datepart is being unidentified.

```sql
SELECT UserID, COUNT(event1) as EventsPerHour, DATEPART(HH, timestamp) as Hour
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY UserID, DATEPART(HH, timestamp)
HAVING COUNT(event1) >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query by using `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp_str)`.

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(event1) as EventsPerHour, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp_str) as Hour
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY UserID, Hour
HAVING EventsPerHour >= 10
```

I obtained this output from my sample data:

[image]